# No matching distribution found for Flask-User When installing the package

Tags: pip, flask-user

I am trying to install Flask-User package for my project (to use the @roles_required decorator) using `pip install Flask-User` in my project environment, but am getting this error in windows. Not sure what's wrong since I can just install the package in another computer

```
(env) PS D:\project> pip install Flask-User
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask-User (from versions: 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 
0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.6.7, 0.6.8, 0.6.9, 0.6.10, 0.6.12, 0.6.13, 0.6.14, 0.6.15, 0.6.16, 0.6.17, 0.6.19, 0.6.20, 0.6.21, 1.0.1.1, 1.0.1.2, 1.0.1.3, 1.0.1.4, 1.0.1.5, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.2.1, 1.0.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask-User
(env) PS D:\project>
```

Answer (score 2):

All [releases](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-User/#history) of Flask-User are marked "YANKED" which means they're not installable.

It seems the project is going out. See https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/issues/341